# android.com training: fragments example not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I started with android 3 days ago and are following the training on android.com.
In the section about fragments I encoutered a NullPointerException caused by
a findViewById() inside a fragment.

Code is copied from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Edit: uploaded the example source to https://github.com/Flikk/Android-training-fragments-basics

news_articles.xml (main):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              ... />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              ..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

ArticleFragment.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText("some text");
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

Now the problem is the updateArticleView().
`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article)` returns null

Now debugging was quite difficult for me.
Is there any way to see the Component Tree or something like that during debug?

---

**What I did**
I was able to work around the bug by trying the following:
`getView().findViewById(R.id.article)`
instead of
`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article)`
did **not** work in the `updateArticleView()` but worked in `onViewCreated()` assigning it to a member variable.

Using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_view)` which is not the ID assigned in the XML but the name of the inflated XML **worked**.

Just using `getView()` also worked

---

**Questions**
It's confusing for a beginner to get examples from the official website that are not working.
I am also not sure why using `getView()` is working.

**Can anyone explain me how the `getView()` and `getActivity()` work in this case by breaking down to Component Tree or something?**

**Also, what is the difference that makes `getView().findViewById(R.id.article)` work in `onViewCreated()` but not in `updateArticleView()`? getView() returns the same View both times.**

I currently have no idea what would be the right to write this `updateArticleView`

Comment: Where does updateArticleView() get called? I did not find it in the example you linked. Can you post your full fragment and activity code?

Comment: @Bmuig It gets called in HeadlinesFragment.java `public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);` mCallback is the activity which is set in the `onAttach`method of the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem myself now.

I have the following structure:

- ViewGroup LinearLayout

  - Fragment with ID: headlines_fragment
  - Fragment with ID: article_fragment

**headlines_fragment**
This Fragment comes from the class `HeadlinesFragment`, which `extends ListFragment` and uses it's default `onCreateView()`
The default `onCreateView` returns a `View` which is a `FrameLayout`

**article_fragment**
This Fragment comes from the class ArticleFragment which inflates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**The Result:**

- ViewGroup LinearLayout

  - FrameLayout with ID: headlines_fragment
  - TextView with ID: article_fragment

In the XML the `TextView` ID was defined as *article*. But by placing it as a Fragment into the ViewGroup, the ID changed to that of the Fragment element.

If the inflated XML from above would enclose the TextView inside a Layout, the ViewGroup would look like this:

**article_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result:**

- ViewGroup LinearLayout

  - FrameLayout with ID: headlines_fragment
  - LinearLayout with ID: article_fragment

    - TextView with ID: **article**

In this case it would be possible to find the TextView by its original ID **article**

At this moment i can only guess where the ID gets changed. I assume that it happens inside or after `onAttach()` of the fragment

Answer (score 1):

`Fragments` are part of your `Activity` but with different view. You use them when you want more than one view to be shown in single `Activity` like `Tabs`.

What happens is whenever `Fragment` is created, it doesn't know about what view would it be given. You have to decide inside `onCreateView`. Its like "Ok, now I am ready, please tell me how should I look like" inside `onCreateView`. Now it's your responsibility to give it a `View`.

So you `inflate` a view which you want to be shown. `article_view` in this case.

Once it's inflated, you'll need to access `Fragment`'s view elements, not `Activity`'s, therefore you have to get reference to that view inside `onCreateView`.

You can either get reference to `View` or individual Elements. Let's say you have a `TextView` in your `article_view`. What you can do is,

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        TextView article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
        article.setText("some text");
        return view;
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        this.view = view;
        return view;
    }

    public void updateArticleView(int position) {
        TextView article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
        article.setText("some text");
        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Make sure you call `updateArticleView` after view is inflated. It means you can call it anywhere instead of `onCreate` (It's `onCreate`, not `onCreateView`. You can definitely call it inside `onCreateView` after inflating the view.

**UPDATE**

I think you are confuse in committing `Fragment` in a view.

Follow the example below to show `Fragment`.

Your main view, let's say `activity_main.xml`, should look like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>

    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
          ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Come to your `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Fragment fragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

You can play with that now how you want. My both examples should work now.

Comment: Your 2nd example is not working, `findViewById()` returns null.   
But like i wrote, it works using `view.findViewById(R.id.article)` in `onViewCreated()`. And no, view is not null inside `updateArticleView()` it gets called after `onCreateView()`. I'll add the xml of article_fragment.xml in my question

Comment: If this is the case, your fragment doesn't contain the view then. Post your complete xml and code to commit fragment.

Comment: I posted the full XML of the article_view.xml in my question now. 
The strange thing is that it works in `onViewCreated`but not in `updateArticleView` How does the View change between those Methods?

Comment: Because you are calling it in a wrong way. See my update

Comment: The Android example is using the v4 support library. I think your update is doing what the `android:name` attribute of the `fragment` tag in main_activity.xml is already doing. I will try your approach and uploaded the example code from Android to github https://github.com/Flikk/Android-training-fragments-basics

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem. I was looking up on what your code is doing different. And all i see is that you bind the fragment dynamically while i do it static in the XML with the android:name attribute.

Comment: There are two problems. 1. You are calling `Fragment`'s method from `Activity`, if `Fragment` is committed, then it should not cause a problem, but you are not making sure of it. May be it's causing a problem. 2. You are finding your `article` in `Activity`, but it's not there. It's in your `Fragment`. You have to find it there by using `View`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by calling `Fragment`s method from Activity. And about finding the view. **It seems like the Fragment is the TextView with the id "article"** But in the Activity can only have 1 id. So it has to choose between "article" and "article_fragment". The cause seems to be that the article_view.xml only contains the TextView element without an enclosing Layout. surrounding that TextView with a layout, allows me to find the TextView with ID "article" in the Activity. And the code is not mine but from android.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best person to help with the theory part, but try this way

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view,container,false);
    this.view = view;
    TextView article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: It's basically what i did in the `onViewCreated()` method. Can I be sure that the View is allready created in the `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Yes, but this way you can do the findViewById on the onCreateView()

Comment: About the getView() question, it's probably because the getView() only work after the OnCreateView, on the end you do return view and the view is no longer null

Comment: I was not asking about `getView()` but the local `View` variable you are using. After assigning the return of the inflate to it. Is it ready to use or could there still be background thread working on it?

Comment: I'm having not sure what is your question, what do you mean by using the View? in this code i believe you can make changes before the return

Comment: Like a article.setText() after the code to bind the article TextView

Comment: My question was if the `inflate()` returns the reference to the view after it is completely inflated. Or is there a possibility that the inflation is still running after the return?

Comment: I don't think so.                                                                                                       View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment view id's are identified by using the inflated view in `onCreateView()` method. When you use `getView()` in onCreateView() it will return null as view is not created yet.

> It works in onViewCreated()

Because when this method is called after the fragment view has been inflated. So getView() will return the inflated view.

You can initialize the view following way:

1. Declare class variable for views.
2. In onCreateView find the reference for the widgets.

   ```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
         article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
         return view;
    }
   ```
3. Now use this `article` textview in your  `updateArticleView` directly to set text.

Comment: That does not explain why `getView().findViewById(R.id.article)` works in `onViewCreated()` but not `updateArticleView()`.    
The `getView()` in `updateArticleView()` does not return null, since it is called by clicking on an item in another ListFragment after everything got already drawn on the screen